# Accessing a Coherence named cache from Clojure

Tags: clojure, oracle-coherence

Having problems accessing caches from the REPL.

I can do (import '(com.tangosol.net CacheFactory) '(com.tangosol.net NamedCache)) and then (. CacheFactory VERSION) without problems.

However when I try (. CacheFactory getCache "TEST") I get an exception :-

```
(Wrapped: Failed to load the factory) null
[Thrown class com.tangosol.util.WrapperException]  

Restarts:
0: [QUIT] Quit to the SLIME top level

Backtrace:
0: com.tangosol.util.Base.ensureRuntimeException(Base.java:283)
1: com.tangosol.net.CacheFactory.
                           getConfigurableCacheFactory(CacheFactory.java:610)
      [No Locals]
```

Has anyone used Clojure with Coherence and could point me to a possible solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tangosol-coherence.xml is correctly setup? Because getCache obtains value configurablecache-factory-config from it

P.S. BTW, for static class members you can use **(Class/method ...)** or **Class/member** syntax

Comment: Yes, the problem was my override config had the wrong cluster name, and therefore did not join my development cluster. I can access the caches now.